# Can't Spring custom auto configuration class have the same name as default auto configuration class

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I'm trying to write a custom auto configuration class to override the behaviour of default auto configuration class.

For instance, imagine I'm trying to override the behaviour of `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAutoConfiguration`.
If I name my custom auto configuration class the same as default one like - `com.rabbit.RabbitAutoConfiguration`, both of them have the same bean name.
I use `@AutoConfigureAfter` in my custom autoconfigure class and the application works fine as expected. However, problem arises when I try to write a test class to test my custom auto configuration class `com.rabbit.RabbitAutoConfiguration`.

Since both have the same bean name, the order in which, I register these classes really matters while writing test cases.

For instance in test class,

```
annotationConfigWebApplicationContext.register(org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAutoConfiguration.class, com.rabbit.RabbitAutoConfiguration.class);
```

has different behaviour compared to

```
annotationConfigWebApplicationContext.register(com.rabbit.RabbitAutoConfiguration.class, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAutoConfiguration.class);
```

However, I managed to overcome this problem by explicitly specifying bean name to my custom autoconfigure class by specifying `@Configuration("customRabbitAutoConfiguration")`.

Shouldn't the class names be same? If so, why is that I see this problem only when writing test class and not when using the real application.

Just wondering is there a better way to do it.

Comment: Because the application doesn't load the `RabbitAutoConfiguration` as that is bound to certain conditions in your test you don't honor those.

Comment: @M. Denium, Thanks for your response!! I don’t quite understand your comment. Can you please be more elaborative. Thanks

Comment: What isn't clear about it? When using auto configuration the Spring Boot `RabbitAutoConfiguration` won't be added due to all the `@ConditionalOn` annotations due to your own `RabbitAutoConfiguration`. This doesn't apply when you create your own context and basically the last one wins.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, as I was away!! Thanks for your reply @Denim. Makes perfect sense.